# How to put php condition for visibility block in drupal 7.14

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm currently using drupal 7.14 and I can not find where to put php code for condition of visibility block.

so in drupal 6.x. I can do it by use **Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE (PHP-mode, experts only)** option on block configuration.

anyone share this?

Comment: This should probably be in drupal.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 6):

Goto to Modules and enable core module `PHP Filter` in order to insert PHP code. 
Then go to a block and at the vertical tab `page` you will see the option to insert PHP code.

***-Notice*** that the user that needs to use PHP code this way he/she has to have the necessary privileges.

Comment: Thank you so much. it work !! and Can you explain me why drupal 6.x can use php code for condition of visibility block without enabled PHP filter module?

Comment: haven't used drupal6 a lot, but in Drupal7 i believe it gives you more control and security to your website that the php filter is not enabled by default.